# detect the class of a child div inside a parent div and then add class or id to the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I know how to add class as well as detect the class of the div in **jQuery** but now I want to  get the class name of the child inside the parent div and then add a class or id to the parent div that hold the child div.

**example:**

```
<div>
    <div class="childdiv">this is the child divident</div>
</div>
```

after the div child class has been get or detected then add class or id to the parent div (in my case, I use `class`)..

**the output should be:**

```
<div class='parentclasshasbeenadded'>
    <div class="childdiv">this is the childdiv</div>
</div>
```

This just an experiment, once this succeed then I'm going to apply this to my actual big bang project, please help me, thanks in advance.

**PS:** I'm open to any suggestions, recommendations and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help to figure things out.

```
$('.parent .child')[0]{
//there is
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
$('div :has(".childdiv")').addClass('parentclasshasbeenadded');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.childdiv').parent().addClass('parentclasshasbeenadded');
```

Above will add `class=parentclasshasbeenadded` to `parent` of `.childdiv`

and to add `id`:

```
$('.childdiv').parent().attr('id', 'someid');
```

To detect class exists you need to use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('div').children().each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('childdiv')) {

    // to add class
    $(this).parent().addClass('parentclasshasbeenadded');

    // to add id
    $(this).parent().attr('id', 'someid');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).children().hasClass("childdiv")) {
    $(this).addClass("Thaparentclasshasbeenadded")
}
```